# redux-saga TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm sure there's a very simple reason why my code isn't working but I have been trying to understand why for a couple days and haven't been making progress.

I'm trying to sign the user in directly after they sign up. Any recommendations on the code itself would be appreciated as well.

```
[Actions][1]
[Types][2]
[User Sagas 1][3]
[User Sagas 2][4]
[User Reducer][5]
[Error][6]
```

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOb0i.png

2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3heqj.png

3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmWiF.png

4: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FTnA.png

5: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoGo3.png

6: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSSsw.png

Comment: Would be helpful if you could say in which file and line the error occurs

Comment: The error is saying the error is in the User Sagas file, the user is able to sign up .. but the error starts when I attempt to sign them in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `SignInStart` and `SignUpSuccess` you need to pass email and password as an object.
like so:

```
export const SignInStart = (email, password) => ({
  type: UserActionTypes.SIGN_IN_START,
  payload: { email, password }
});
```

because your saga function (`signIn`), expect to get a payload object in this shape:

```
 const payload = {
     email: 'example'
    password: 'password'
}
```

Comment: It did go further than it did before but its saying email and password us undefined. Am I passing it through wrong?

Comment: can you show the updated `user.actions.js`,  `user.sagas.js` file and the `Signup` component Submit function (where you call the `SignInStart`)?

Comment: I was able to make it work with your help, thank you!